# Constant current source - unexplained issues

Tags: potentiometer, current-source, constant-current, voltage-reference, current-mirror

I have been puzzling over this for days now, and cannot for the life of me figure it out...

I have a constant current source set up to use as an analog dimmer for my LM3429 LED driver. I have made very slight changes in order to use a digital potentiometer and avoid issues that arise from bad tolerancing of that part.

Here is a stripped back version of the cicruit I am testing on.

What I have observed so far:

- When unconnected the LM4120 reference give a stable 5V.
- The potentiometer is definitely changing
- When top of potentiometer is connected to reference, Reference drops to 3.9V

I really have no idea what is going on here. Can anyone help me debug this?

[image]

LM4120 DS: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4120.pdf

LM3429 DS (page 14): http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3429.pdf

Comment: Are you sure this schematic is drawn correctly? Shouldn't IN/EN be tied to 6.6V and the reference pin floating?

Comment: My mistake, well spotted. It is correct on the testing circuit, I just cobbled that schematic together quickly. Obviously trying to diagnose the problem has taken it's toll on me! Fixed it now.

Comment: What power supply does your digital pot use?

Comment: The pot uses the same 3v supply that powers the control side of things. I didn't think that should affect the operation since the digital pot seems to just be a series of switches on resistor banks. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: What is Vcc it should be significantly greater than 5V .Use balancing resistors in the emitters of Q2a Q2b

Comment: Following on Andy's inquiry- your digital pot needs a supply at least as high as the highest voltage any of the 'pot' terminals will see. So it needs a 5V supply.

Comment: Swap in a physical pot for the digital pot. My guess is that it will all work. Then, restore the digital pot and debug (check the max input voltage relative to Vcc on the spec sheet).

Comment: VCC is roughly 6.6V. Thanks for the feedback everyone, I'll give things a try. Is anyone able to point out where it says on the MSP4151 datasheet about the supply being as large as the output? Why does this have an affect on a resistor network? is it due to the switch operation/bias internally?